# Comparing values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Using Python 3.3

Hi, I'm pretty new to programming/Python, so please don't go into too in-depth/complex methods of solving this problem.

I have a dictionary in which the keys are the person's name, and each of the key's values is a list of the names of the person's friends. For example:

```
friends_of_person = {'Albus': ['Ron', 'Hermione'], 'Harry': ['Ron', 'Hermione', 'Neville']}
```

This dictionary can be longer.

What my question is, how do I write a for loop or code that will loop through the values and compare each of the values to each of the values of another key's values. To make this clearer, let's use the above example. Albus is a friend to Harry, Ron, and Hermione. Harry is a friend to Ron and Hermione.

But I want to compare 'Ron' to the 'Ron', 'Hermione', and 'Neville' from the key Harry.
And then what I want is to see if 'Ron' is a friend of Harry. IF and ONLY if Ron is a friend of Harry, then I want to make 'Harry' as a potential friend of 'Albus'. The case applies to when comparing 'Hermione' to the 'Ron' and 'Hermione' from Harry's values. - this is like mutual friends.

The following is the code I've written, but it didn't seem to yield the correct answer.

```
friends_of_person = {'Albus': ['Ron', 'Hermione'], 'Harry': ['Ron', 'Hermione', 'Neville']}

for person in friends_of_person:

   friends_list = friends_of_person[person]

   for friend in friends_list:

       recommendation = ''

       for another_person in friends_of_person:

          if friend in friends_of_person[another_person]:

             recommendation = another_person
```

It doesn't seem correct. But if anyone can give me hints/tips to put me on the right direction, it'll be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: So basically you want to recommend someone if he/she is friend with at least two of your friends?

Comment: Exactly! In this case, it would be recommending Harry as a friend to Albus

Answer (score 0):

Use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to check the intersection of people's friend list:

```
In [352]: lst1=friends_of_person['Albus']

In [353]: lst2=friends_of_person['Harry']

In [354]: lst1
Out[354]: ['Ron', 'Hermione']

In [355]: lst2
Out[355]: ['Ron', 'Hermione', 'Neville']

In [356]: set(lst1)&set(lst2)
Out[356]: set(['Hermione', 'Ron'])
```

Comment: Our instructions were to not use any approach not taught though...and one of them is intersection...

Comment: @user3448498 that's ridiculous... nobody here knows what you have learned and what not. You can learn it yourself ;)

Comment: well, only the materials taught in first yr python

Answer (score 0):

@zhangxaochen's answer using sets is in my opinion the neatest. Nonetheless, if you want to use lists you could do something like:

```
friends = {'Albus': ['Ron', 'Hermione'], 'Harry': ['Ron', 'Hermione', 'Neville']}

def mutual_friends(a, b):
    return [x for x in friends[a] if x in friends[b]]
```

Note that's re-coding set intersection (EDIT: if you have been instructed not to use set intersection then this solution is good since you code it yourself :)).

So

```
def recommendations(x):
    result = []

    for f in friends.keys():
        if f != x and mutual_friends(x, f) > 1:
            result.append(f)

    return result
```

Basically, for a given person `x`, find all the people that have more than one mutual friend with them. You could change it to `== 2` if you want exactly 2 mutual friends.

Answer (score 0):

If you want approach using only simple iterations and basic features, here you go:

```
for friend in friends_of_person['Albus']:
    recommendation = []
    for person, friends in friends_of_person.items():
        if person == 'Albus':
            continue # we don't need anyone who already is his friend
        for potential in friends:
            if potential in friends_of_person['Albus'] and potential not in recommendation:
                recommendation.append(potential)
print(potential)
   ...: 
Neville
```

PS. It's ugly, but that's what OP wanted...